# Append values with different lengths from one dictionary to another

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary with list values of a different length. I'm needed to get the values that are in the same position associated to the same key in a new dictionary.

Original Dictionay {A: [1,2] , B: [3,4,5]}

New Dictionary: {A: [1,3], B: [2,4], C: [5]}

I tried a for loop and wrapping my values in zip_longest, but am still getting a list index out of range error.

```
for x in range(1, max([len(v) for v in sub_folder_notebooks.values()])):
    notebook_step[x] = zip_longest([elem[x] for elem in sub_folder_notebooks.values()])
```

Comment: Question - how to you decide/get the new_dict *keys* - 'C' in the example?

Comment: the index error is due to indexing a list that has n elements with an index i>n. in your example it must occur when x=2 and you are trying to get elem[2] from list [1,2] (the values of the jkey 'A').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a condition when looping through the values of the dict `sub_folder_notebooks` to make sure that you can access elem[x]. not the nicest way but should do the trick:

```
for x in range(0, max([len(v) for v in sub_folder_notebooks.values()])):
notebook_step[x] = zip_longest([elem[x] for elem in sub_folder_notebooks.values() if len(elem)>x])
```

I start from x=0 because you want to have the first element as well.